# how to auto arrange model attribute values in Yii?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sorting, yii

I have a db table that contains three attributes: (id, image, order).

id: is the primary key, id of the image.
image: name of the image.
order: number, representing the order number of the image to be viewed with respect to.

for example:

let us say that we have these three records in the db:

### id - image - order

1  - image A - 1

2  - image B - 2

3  - image C - 3

then we want to add a new record that have the following values (4, image D, 2), but the `order 2` is already taken by the image B, a function that called `arrange()` will give the image D order 2 and push the images B and C +1 order, so the new table will be:

### id - image - order

1  - image A - 1

2  - image B - 3

3  - image C - 4

4  - image D - 2

so the function arrange is working by pushing the order attribute down or up, and concatenates the order attribute values to each other if a record deleted, I hope the idea of function arrange() is clear now, here is the code of the function:

```
protected function actionArrange($mod, $neworder, $oldorder, $operation){

            $model = $mod::model()->findAll();

            if($operation == ''){

                if($oldorder == '' && $neworder != ''){

                    foreach($model as $m){

                        if($neworder == $m->order){

                            $tmpmodel = $mod::model()->findAll('t.order>='.$neworder);

                            foreach($tmpmodel as $tm){

                                $md = $this->loadModel($tm->id);
                                $md->order = $tm->order+1;
                                $md->save();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                elseif($oldorder != '' && $neworder!= ''){

                    if($oldorder == $neworder)

                        return;

                    elseif($oldorder < $neworder){

                        $tmpmodel = $mod::model()->findAll("t.order<=$neworder AND t.order>= $oldorder+1");

                        foreach ($tmpmodel as $tm){

                            $md = $this->loadModel($tm->id);
                            $md->order = $tm->order-1;
                            $md->save();
                        }
                    }

                    elseif($oldorder > $neworder) {

                        $tmpmodel = $mod::model()->findAll('t.order>='.$neworder.' AND t.order<='.$oldorder-1);

                        foreach ($tmpmodel as $tm){

                            $m = $this->loadModel($tm->id);
                            $m->order = $tm->order+1;
                            $m->save();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            elseif('delete' == strtolower($operation)){

                if($oldorder != ''){

                    $tmpmodel = $mod::model()->findAll("t.order>$oldorder");

                    if(!empty($tmpmodel))

                        foreach($tmpmodel as $tm){

                            $m = $this->loadModel($tm->id);
                            $m->order = $tm->order-1;
                            $m->save();
                        }
                }
            }

            return;
        }
```

the parameters of the function:

$mod: is new model , for example: $mod = new Images;

$neworder: is the order attribute value that will replace the $oldorder in the db.

$oldorder: is the current value of the order attribute in the db.

$operation: can take 'delete' string, used to till the function to concatenates the order attribute values because there is a record will be deleted.

Finally, I want to hear your opinions about this function, and how it can be enhanced?

Comment: I would not do this via acticve record because that is very expensive. You can do a simple sql query before inserting the new data: `UPDATE image SET order=order+1 WHERE order >= 2;` assuming the order of the to-be-inserted row is 2. Then just insert the new record.

Comment: And you can do what chris is saying in the `onBeforeSave` and `onAfterDelete` functions of active record. As it is something that always needs to happen.